# TRANSPOSE formula array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I want to make the formula array function easier

I wrote some code but it does not insert my copy range as I expected:

```
Sub copy_link()

Dim copyrange As Range
Dim pasterange As Range

Set copyrange = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Choose the copy area", Type:=8)
Set pasterange = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Choose the paste area", Type:=8)

pasterange.FormulaArray = "=TRANSPOSE(copyrange)"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
pasterange.FormulaArray = "=TRANSPOSE(" & copyrange.Address & ")"
```

Your way would just insert the word "copyrange" into the formula in Excel, and that is totally meaningless to Excel. It only makes sense in VBA, so you will have to make VBA interpret it. this is why it is outside the quotation marks.

You also need to retrieve the range's address, not its value, hence the `.Address` part.

**Edit**

```
Sub copy_link()

Dim copyrange As Range
Dim pasterange As Range
Dim RowNum As Long
Dim ColNum As Long

Set copyrange = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Choose the copy area", Type:=8)
Set pasterange = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Choose the paste area", Type:=8)

RowNum = copyrange.Rows.Count
ColNum = copyrange.Columns.Count

 pasterange.Cells(1).Resize(ColNum, RowNum).FormulaArray = "=TRANSPOSE(" & copyrange.Address & ")"


End Sub
```

`Cells(1)` makes sure that we start "creating" the output range from the top left cell of `pasterange`. `.resize(ColNum, RowNum)` resizes it to be the transposed variant of the `copyrange`.

Maybe easier to understand (but does the same, just more verbose):

```
.Resize(RowSize:=ColNum,ColumnSize:=RowNum)
```

Comment: Is there any way to set the pasterange only as the Upper-left corner and excel will take the range by the (transposed) dimmension of copyrange

Comment: Yes there is. Count the cells in the first range, and resize your second range with that. See my updated answer.